# Ajax code is not working in Safari, Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, safari

Why Does my Ajax Not work on Google Chrome Or IE but works on FireFox, And how can i make it work
This Ajax Code is not working in chrome and safari . i want to update with ajax i tried my best some body help me please .

```
<script> function checkasda<?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];?>() {
    var quanti = document.getElementById("quanti<?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];?>").value; 
    var prodi = <?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];?>; 
    // alert( quanti +' '+ prodi); var dataString = 'quanti='+ encodeURIComponent(quanti) + '&prodi='+ encodeURIComponent(prodi) ; $.ajax({ async: false, type: "POST", url: "updatecart.php", data: dataString, cache: false, success: function(html){ if(alert('Done')){} else window.location.reload(); window.location.reload(); } }); } 
</script>
```

Comment: <script>
function checkasda<?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];?>()
{
  var quanti = document.getElementById("quanti<?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];?>").value;
   var prodi = <?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];?>;
 // alert( quanti +' '+ prodi);
 
  var dataString = 'quanti='+ encodeURIComponent(quanti) + '&prodi='+ encodeURIComponent(prodi) ;
        $.ajax({
   async: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "updatecart.php",
   data: dataString,
  cache: false,
 success: function(html){
 if(alert('Done')){}
else    window.location.reload(); 
window.location.reload();
  }
});
}
</script>

Comment: Please edit your question and add your script. It difficult to see what you did when you add it in the comment section.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: Can you please add your full sourcecode, it's impossible to help you with this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your id is numeric and Chrome and IE fail because cannot interprete to concatenate..., convert to char/string,

This works fine on Chrome:
pagesRecordprol=array('id'=>'1');

This doesn't works on Chrome:
pagesRecordprol=array('id'=>1);

```
<pre>
    --php--
$pagesRecordprolarray = array('id' => '1');
foreach ($pagesRecordprolarray as $pagesRecordprol) {
    echo $pagesRecordprol['id'];
       --endphp--

    <script> function checkasda<?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id']; ?>() {
        var quanti = document.getElementById("quanti<?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id']; ?>").value;
                var prodi = <?php echo $pagesRecordprol['id']; ?>;
                // alert( quanti +' '+ prodi); var dataString = 'quanti='+ encodeURIComponent(quanti) + '&prodi='+ encodeURIComponent(prodi) ; $.ajax({ async: false, type: "POST", url: "updatecart.php", data: dataString, cache: false, success: function(html){ if(alert('Done')){} else window.location.reload(); window.location.reload(); } }); } 
    </script>
    --php--
}
    --endphp--
</pre>
```

Regards